# Java: How to get individual int values out of int[][]

Tags: java, int, extract

I have an int[][] object. It is defined in my code as below:

```
public int[][] position = {
    {20, 30}, {73, 91},
    {82, 38}
};
```

Would it be possible to get the value of the first value (on the left) within each of the pairs of parentheses and store them as individual int variables using a for loop? Basically, is it possible to extract the "20", "73" and "82" and store them into int variables individually?

Comment: I apologize if my question seems vague. I am new to Java and I would assume that my terminology is not yet up to scratch. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: I upvoted, because you are new and you wrapped the code into code blocks.

Comment: @Adil Soomro: Thanks mate. I saw the code icon and it made it heaps easier to read so I clicked it. I will keep doing that then.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
for(int[] x : position){
  int y = x[0];
  // Do something with y...
}
```

Or just:

```
int x = position[0][0];
int y = position[1][0];
int y = position[2][0];
```

Comment: That is EXACTLY what I have been looking for. You're a lifesaver mate. Thanks a lot! Have a good one and Merry Christmas.

Comment: @DillonChaffey: if that did indeed help you solve your problem, please consider accepting it - see [how does accepting an answer work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for what that's all about.

Comment: @ziesemer: I just learned how to accept answers and accepted your's. Thanks again for your help.